# cshell cannot set array of strings with spaces

Tags: csh

I am new to c shell. I've been trying to define an array of commands then run them using a loop but it keeps parsing the commands word by word instead of command by command.

The code is :

```
#!/bin/csh


set commands=("./cmd option1 option2" \
"./cmd option1 option2" \
"./cmd option1 option2" \
"./cmd option1 option2" \
)
foreach  c ($commands)

        echo $c
        $c
end
#EOF
```

The output is :

```
./cmd 
Output 
option1
command not found
option2
command not found
```

I think the error is in the loop, but I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$command` to `$command:q`.

For example:

```
% cat foo.csh
#!/bin/csh -f

set arr = ( 'zero one' 'two three' )
foreach elem ($arr:q)
    echo $elem:q
end
% ./foo.csh
zero one
two three
%
```

This is one case where the `:q` suffix works and enclosing the variable reference in double quotes does not.

Note that I've added `-f` to the `#!` line. This tells `csh` *not* to load your startup files, which makes your script slightly faster and, more important, avoids unintentional dependencies on your own environment. csh or tcsh scripts should (almost) always have a `-f` on the `#!` line. (This does not apply to sh, ksh, bash, or zsh scripts; for those shells, `-f` has a different meaning.)

> I am new to c shell

**Perfect!**  That means this is a great time to switch to a shell that's more programmer-friendly, like bash or even sh.

bash supports arrays, though the syntax is a bit less convenient than csh's -- but bash's behavior is more consistent. One example: I'm not sure that I could prove from csh's and/or tcsh's manual that `:q` would work in this case; I had to use trial and error. I've used csh for many years, and I frequently run into this kind of thing.

Read this: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: Good show. Had forgotten about `:q` and probably wouldn't have figured out that usage anyway. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. I am familiar with bash but cshell is needed for a project. I'm still in shock by how counter intuitive it is.

Comment: @east.charm: Does "cshell is needed for a project" mean that it's a requirement for a homework assignment? Really, requiring csh makes sense only if the goal is to learn csh. (I used csh, and later tcsh, for many years; I finally switched to bash for both scripting and interactive use a few years ago.)

Comment: Not a school assignment. I'm interning in a company that uses it :(

Comment: @east.charm: My sympathies.